# Prevent default click action based on another class existing on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following CSS code that when the .dashboard-actions class is clicked opens up a dropdown menu. Once clicked the 2nd div in the tree .dropdown changes to class="dropdown open" (indicates the dropdown menu is open/visible), once the user clicks off the open class is removed and the dropdown menu disappears (as expected).

I want to be able using some form of javascript (AngularJS 1.3 or jQuery) be able to do some logic to recognise when the dropdown is 'open' - if so, if a user clicks anywhere else on the screen, for instance the href below the div it will open 'close' the dropdown by removing the 'open' class rather than doing that default action, how could I best approach this?

```
<div class="dashboard-actions ellipsis">
   <div class="dropdown" stop-event>
      <div class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
           <span class="material-icons">more_vert</span>
      </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1">
           <div>
            <div ng-include src="'templates/menu.html'" ng-repeat="x in item.x"></div>
          </div>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="interaction-body">
  <a href="https://somecdn.com/t51.2885-15/aaa.jpg" ng-href="https://somecdn.com/t51.2885-15/aaa.jpg" target="_blank" stop-event="">
  <img ng-src="https://somecdn.com/t51.2885-15/aaa.jpg" src="https://somecdn.com/t51.2885-15/aaa.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are searching for this

```
//Some code

$('.dropdown-menu').each({
    if($(this).hasClass('open')){
        // Do something
        // $(this).removeClass('open');
    }
});

//More code
```